# UIColor extension for .cgColor colors?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Here is my UIColor extension:

```
extension UIColor {   
    // custom red
    public class var customRed: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 59/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

How do I append cgColors to it?

```
UIColor.someColor.cgColor
```

Comment: I don´t see what you are trying? you can return in your extension a cgColor instead

Comment: can you explain more about what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
extension CGColor{
    public class var customRed: CGColor {
        return UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 59/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    }
}
```

Use it

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = CGColor.customRed
```

Hope this helps you